# Count operation in reduceByKey in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

```
val temp1 = tempTransform.map({ temp => ((temp.getShort(0), temp.getString(1)), (USAGE_TEMP.getDouble(2), USAGE_TEMP.getDouble(3)))})
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => ((x._1+y._1),(x._2+y._2)))
```

Here I have performed Sum operation But Is it possible to do **count** operation inside reduceByKey.

Like what i think,

```
reduceByKey((x, y) => (math.count(x._1),(x._2+y._2)))
```

But this is not working any suggestion please.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "count"? Do you mean counting the number of records per key? Or counting distinct `x._1` values? Perhaps give a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Do you mean counting the number of records per key? 
Yes.(Like aggregate operation).
ex . 
math.sum(x._2+y._2) give sum of all records which satisfied key.
Same way i am searching for Count operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, counting is equivalent to summing `1`s, so just map the first item in each value tuple into `1` and sum both parts of the tuple like you did before:

```
val temp1 = tempTransform.map { temp => 
   ((temp.getShort(0), temp.getString(1)), (1, USAGE_TEMP.getDouble(3)))
}
.reduceByKey((x, y) => ((x._1+y._1),(x._2+y._2)))
```

Result would be an `RDD[((Short, String), (Int, Double))]` where the first item in the value tuple (the `Int`) is the number of original records matching that key.

That's actually the classic map-reduce example - [word count](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. RDD provide iterator model for lazy computation. So every element will be visited only once.

If you really want to do sum as described, re-partition your rdd first, then use mapWithPartition, implement your calculation in closure( Keep in mind that elements in RDD is not in order).